# Why are the TimeSpan values different between netcoreapp2.1 and netcoreapp3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I noticed some of my unit tests failing when I went from netcoreapp2.1 to netcoreapp3.1.

The following code has different results:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var seconds = 0.81960;
        var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

        Console.WriteLine($"seconds:{seconds}");
        Console.WriteLine($"timeSpan:{timeSpan}");
        Console.WriteLine($"timeSpan.Milliseconds:{timeSpan.Milliseconds}");
        Console.WriteLine($"timeSpan.Ticks:{timeSpan.Ticks}");
    }
    }
}

/*
core 2.1 and Framework 4.8 ROUNDS to nearest ms
seconds:0.8196
timeSpan:00:00:00.8200000
timeSpan.Milliseconds:820
timeSpan.Ticks:8200000
*/

/*
core 3.1 no longer rounds to nearest ms

seconds:0.8196
timeSpan:00:00:00.8196000
timeSpan.Milliseconds:819
timeSpan.Ticks:8196000
*/
```

It's not a display formatting thing, you can see that from the underlying value of ticks.

Why are they different between dotnet core versions?

Comment: There isn't one. TimeSpan stores ticks, not milliseconds. The actual content is returned by the `TimeSpan.Ticks` property. What you see is the difference in formatting floating point numbers. The old behaviour incorrectly limited precision in some cases

Comment: Hmm there is a open issue here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13230

Comment: Which explains that this is purely a floating point formatting issue. Did you check the *actual* data, ie the ticks? The TimeSpan stores ticks *only*. All other values are generated by dividing the ticks by TicksPerMillisecond, TicksPerSecond etc

Comment: In your case, the TimeSpan value is generated by multiplying the original floating point number with TicksPerSecond to produce Ticks. Formatting requires dividing Ticks by TicksPerMillisecond to produce the millisecond part.

Comment: Event the *original* floating point value is **NOT** `0.82`. That's a result of rounding to 15 places during formatting. If you specified a larger number of digit you'd get the 9s: `String.Format("{0:N20}",6560d / 8000)` produces `0.81999999999999995115`

Comment: Finally, [TimeSpan.Milliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.milliseconds?view=netframework-4.8) is an integer produced by rounding, not the actual result of dividing Ticks by TicksPerMillisecond

Comment: A typical reason for a floating point number to be off by a single bit is the process architecture.  Some odds that the 2.1 unit test runner ran in 32-bit mode and you now get 64-bit mode.  The legacy x86 jitter uses the FPU to compute, it operates with 80 bit precision internally.  x64 uses SSE, 64 bit precision.  Tens of thousands of SO questions were the result.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've worked it out. In core 2.1 and in Framework 4.8 FromSeconds and FromMilliseconds return a TimeSpan rounded to the nearest Millisecond ie ticks is 8,200,000. In 3.1 FromSeconds and FromMilliseconds do not round so ticks is 8199999...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?view=netcore-3.1) means by "Returns a System.TimeSpan that represents a specified number of seconds, where the specification is accurate to the nearest millisecond." But the example output they provide in the documentation clearly shows that the output is rounded to 1ms. The documented output now does NOT match the behaviour in 3.1.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My question is completely different to the one you've posted as a duplicate.

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars it's the exact same question. Your value (`6560d / 8000`) is not `0.82`, it's `0.81999999999`. *Formatting* displayed it this way though. If you used *greater* precision in `Console.WriteLine()` you'd get the 9s. If you want the string to appear a certain way, you can use a different format string

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars perhaps the *real* question is *why do you care*? What is the actual problem? Why would the formatted value of a timespan's milliseconds affect your application? This is *guaranteed* to lose precision. If you care about the exact value shouldn't you be using the `Ticks` property instead? In fact, *have* you tried comparing the `Ticks` property ? Have you found any difference between .NET Core 2.1 and 3.1 ?

Comment: I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars as for what is actually going on, you can check the source, both for [.NET Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,01f3edc72026f8e7) and [.NET Core 3](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/TimeSpan.cs#L198). The real difference is how the input is converted to ticks. It looks like the old code essentially performed a `ceiling` operation that converted `0.819999999` to `0.82`. The new code doesn't do that

Comment: No it didn't ceil it, it rounded it to the nearest ms. Why do I care? Because rounding to the nearest ms is the behaviour documented by Microsoft, and I want the value rounded to the nearest ms. It's not a big deal, now I know I'll do the rounding myself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can see why "6560d / 8000" in the original question was misleading. Please can you re-open the question and post your comment as the difference is that they no longer round it in the FromSeconds method, when they did before? I can then mark that as accepted. I think this will be a valuable question for some.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please can you reopen this question and remove the erroneous duplicate tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between dotnet core 2.1 and 3.1 (circa end of 2019) the behaviour of [System.TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1) [changed](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/24279), so that the [factory methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?view=netcore-3.1) no longer round to the nearest 1ms.

There is a github issue about this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13230).

Beware: The current documentation has not been updated to reflect the change in behaviour, the output of the example code is now incorrect on the site: [System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?view=netcore-3.1).

In .net core 2.1 and the Net Framework the TimeSpan created is rounded to the nearest ms:

```
      FromSeconds          TimeSpan
      -----------          --------
            0.001          00:00:00.0010000
           0.0015          00:00:00.0020000
          12.3456          00:00:12.3460000
      123456.7898        1.10:17:36.7900000
  1234567898.7654    14288.23:31:38.7650000
                1          00:00:01
               60          00:01:00
             3600          01:00:00
            86400        1.00:00:00
        1801220.2       20.20:20:20.2000000
```

In .net core 3.1 it is not rounded to the nearest ms (for example 12.3456):

```
      FromSeconds          TimeSpan
      -----------          --------
            0.001          00:00:00.0010000
           0.0015          00:00:00.0015000
          12.3456          00:00:12.3455999
      123456.7898        1.10:17:36.7898000
  1234567898.7654    14288.23:31:38.7654000
                1          00:00:01
               60          00:01:00
             3600          01:00:00
            86400        1.00:00:00
        1801220.2       20.20:20:20.2000000
```